# Not able to use `return` in second operand of ternary

Tags: javascript

I want to return a value if a condition is met, but perform a function if it isn't.

I'm getting an error with

```
function is_equal(a,b){
    a === b ? return true : do_something(a,b);
}
```

but I get the error. `Unexpected token return` Though once when I did it, I got `Unexpected token false`!

This works:

```
return a === b ? true : do_something(a,b);
```

but does this in some way return something from a function that's not meant to return anything? Is a ternary not the right choice for this? The MDN page has no documentation that specifies it shouldn't be used like so. It does show them being used in just about every other conceivable way.. Thanks!

Comment: You're right.  I removed it. :)

Comment: You can't have a statement (such as `return`) inside of an expression (such as a ternary operation).

Comment: small quibble but that's weird code; you'd expect something that returns true under one condition to return false the rest of the time; I suppose it works if do_something(a,b) also returns a boolean.

Comment: You can do `return a === b || void doSomething(a, b);` since the `void` operator evaluates to undefined, you'll get the same return value when `a === b` is false as you would without any `return` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get an error is that the operands to the conditional operator are [*expressions*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12), but [`return`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9) is a [*statement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12). In JavaScript, you can put an expression where a statement is expected, but not the other way around. Trying to use `return` within an operand to the conditional operator is invalid for the same reason that `var a = return false;` is invalid.

> I want to return a value if a condition is met, but perform a function if it isn't.

No pun, but this is what `if` statements are for:

```
function is_equal(a,b){
    if (a === b) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        do_something(a,b);
    }
}
```

Note that that means `is_equal` returns `undefined` if you call `do_something`. Alternately:

```
function is_equal(a,b){
    return a === b ? true : do_something(a,b);
}
```

...if you want to return the result of `do_something`, or:

```
function is_equal(a,b){
    if (a === b) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        do_something(a,b);
        return false;
    }
}
```

You **can** do the above on one line, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
function is_equal(a,b){
    return a === b ? true : (do_something(a,b), false);
}
```

That will return `true` when they're equal, or call `do_something` and then return `false` if they aren't.

Comment: Well, that's true. I just wonder why it's disallowed. Perhaps I should edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: @thomas: I added a couple of options for you. The short answer to the "why" question is that the ternary operator's operands are *expressions*, but `return` is a *statement*.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend it, out of curiosity

Comment: @thomas: Debugging. It's much easier to read and debug the `if` version. If you use an aggressive minifier / compressor / packer / [compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), you can get the release build runtime benefit of that last example without the pain of trying to debug that code in a debug/testing build.

Comment: Your last attempt doesn't work because the conditional operator bounds tighter than the comma. You need parentheses around `(do_something(a,b), false)`, otherwise it always returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the conditional operator that way. Just use an `if`:

```
function is_equal(a,b) {
    if (a === b) return true;
    do_something(a,b);
}
```

See [the EcmaScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12) on exactly what's allowed as expressions in the conditional operator.